# Spring MVC home directory 404 Error Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm studying Spring MVC, and I stuck almost at the start. I've followed the video about creating first MVC app but it's not working for me. I want to get *main.jsp* as start page, following the config but the page is not loading, I'm getting 404 all the time.
I've create a new Maven project. Then I've add Spring MVC framework support for the project, create web.xml and spring-mvc-demo-servlet for Spring configuration.
I've checked my project several times, but unsuccessful. Also, Ive checked similar topics but also wasn't able to found the solution.

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHyer.jpg)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <spring.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>



<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.spring" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**HomeController**

```
package com.test.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main";
    }
```

Comment: first change your servlet `Spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and in your controller class add a request type GET eg: `@RequestMapping("/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. This may help you

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried clean and build your project

Comment: Yep, I did. In Maven panel I made 'clean' then install. Also 'Build - > Rebuild'. All the process looks fine, but the app is not working.

Comment: Once try removing <init-param> from <servlet> in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think [WebApplicationInitalizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) is simplier for begining with Spring 5 and Intellij.

1) Add a `WebMvcConfig` class to your `com.test.spring` package like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.spring"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
   }
```

2) Move your WEB-INF folder to a new folder `src/main/webapp` (mabe you'll have it as source folder by right cli clicking on it)

3) Remove your `web.xml` and `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml` files and all your old web folder

4) Add an application initializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

Finally right click on AppInitializer class and then Run it...

Optionnally, you could add Tomcat to your Maven `pom.xml` and then run command `mvn tomcat7:run` :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lof for your answer **Karbos**, however I had to find the solution exactly for the sources I provided, cause otherwise I wouldn't be able to continie the course on Udemy...

I solve the issue, but the most creepy moment is that I have no idea how I made it. I added several changes to the project. 
Changes in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Changes in pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and some others I may didnt notice cause did it automaticly.

So the issue took one and a half day for me. Feel myself so retarded...

Comment: That what I said : `I think WebApplicationInitalizer is simplier for begining with Spring 5 and Intellij.`